# MongoDB replication failure

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to debug an odd issue that results in the failure or a replica set secondary becoming out of date and unable to catchup with the primary (running on AWS, AWS linux).

The typical replication lag is <1 sec.

There appears to be a correlation with the secondary becoming out of date and the primary running out of logging space, i.e. /var/log/mongodb/.

The oplog is stored on a different drive and this has >50GB of free space.

Question: Could the failure of the primary to create logs result in a replication failure? I have been unable to locate anything in the docs or online that may confirm this.

Edit to add, output of db.printReplicationInfo():

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.printReplicationInfo()
configured oplog size:   30720MB
log length start to end: 2238secs (0.62hrs)
oplog first event time:  Mon Nov 09 2015 16:36:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)
oplog last event time:   Mon Nov 09 2015 17:13:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)
now:                     Mon Nov 09 2015 17:13:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

Edit to add, full output of local db.oplog.rs.stats():

```
{
    "ns" : "local.oplog.rs",
    "count" : 197021,
    "size" : 32227028695,
    "avgObjSize" : 163571,
    "storageSize" : 11432701952,
    "capped" : true,
    "max" : -1,
    "maxSize" : NumberLong("32212254720"),
    "wiredTiger" : {
        "metadata" : {
            "formatVersion" : 1,
            "oplogKeyExtractionVersion" : 1
        },
        "creationString" : "allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1,oplogKeyExtractionVersion=1),block_allocation=best,block_compressor=snappy,cache_resident=0,checkpoint=(WiredTigerCheckpoint.44462=(addr=\"01e30119f281e455da0eb9e30d626b89e457acebd0e30d627488e4c14bdd50808080e502a9710fc0e502984f4fc0\",order=44462,time=1447092664,size=11145277440,write_gen=190060665)),checkpoint_lsn=(174452,45957760),checksum=on,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,id=9,internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=,internal_page_max=4KB,key_format=q,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=32KB,leaf_value_max=64MB,memory_page_max=10m,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,prefix_compression=0,prefix_compression_min=4,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,value_format=u,version=(major=1,minor=1)",
        "type" : "file",
        "uri" : "statistics:table:collection-6-8821970786560075304",
        "LSM" : {
            "bloom filters in the LSM tree" : 0,
            "bloom filter false positives" : 0,
            "bloom filter hits" : 0,
            "bloom filter misses" : 0,
            "bloom filter pages evicted from cache" : 0,
            "bloom filter pages read into cache" : 0,
            "total size of bloom filters" : 0,
            "sleep for LSM checkpoint throttle" : 0,
            "chunks in the LSM tree" : 0,
            "highest merge generation in the LSM tree" : 0,
            "queries that could have benefited from a Bloom filter that did not exist" : 0,
            "sleep for LSM merge throttle" : 0
        },
        "block-manager" : {
            "file allocation unit size" : 4096,
            "blocks allocated" : 190152428,
            "checkpoint size" : 11145277440,
            "allocations requiring file extension" : 225612,
            "blocks freed" : 189847759,
            "file magic number" : 120897,
            "file major version number" : 1,
            "minor version number" : 0,
            "file bytes available for reuse" : 93298688,
            "file size in bytes" : 11432701952
        },
        "btree" : {
            "btree checkpoint generation" : 44481,
            "column-store variable-size deleted values" : 0,
            "column-store fixed-size leaf pages" : 0,
            "column-store internal pages" : 0,
            "column-store variable-size leaf pages" : 0,
            "pages rewritten by compaction" : 0,
            "number of key/value pairs" : 0,
            "fixed-record size" : 0,
            "maximum tree depth" : 5,
            "maximum internal page key size" : 368,
            "maximum internal page size" : 4096,
            "maximum leaf page key size" : 3276,
            "maximum leaf page size" : 32768,
            "maximum leaf page value size" : 67108864,
            "overflow pages" : 0,
            "row-store internal pages" : 0,
            "row-store leaf pages" : 0
        },
        "cache" : {
            "bytes read into cache" : NumberLong("30740995584012"),
            "bytes written from cache" : NumberLong("29998939159917"),
            "checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 394628,
            "unmodified pages evicted" : 164578679,
            "page split during eviction deepened the tree" : 1173,
            "modified pages evicted" : 61796390,
            "data source pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted" : 10970507,
            "hazard pointer blocked page eviction" : 7932631,
            "internal pages evicted" : 3553083,
            "pages split during eviction" : 3825008,
            "in-memory page splits" : 15025,
            "overflow values cached in memory" : 0,
            "pages read into cache" : 175450372,
            "overflow pages read into cache" : 0,
            "pages written from cache" : 190063507
        },
        "compression" : {
            "raw compression call failed, no additional data available" : 0,
            "raw compression call failed, additional data available" : 0,
            "raw compression call succeeded" : 0,
            "compressed pages read" : 173302623,
            "compressed pages written" : 170315036,
            "page written failed to compress" : 22,
            "page written was too small to compress" : 19748044
        },
        "cursor" : {
            "create calls" : 4043133,
            "insert calls" : 230047485,
            "bulk-loaded cursor-insert calls" : 0,
            "cursor-insert key and value bytes inserted" : NumberLong("29150212316581"),
            "next calls" : 730226547,
            "prev calls" : 37,
            "remove calls" : 4040833,
            "cursor-remove key bytes removed" : 36367497,
            "reset calls" : 583047853,
            "search calls" : 328774626,
            "search near calls" : 5144225,
            "update calls" : 0,
            "cursor-update value bytes updated" : 0
        },
        "reconciliation" : {
            "dictionary matches" : 0,
            "internal page multi-block writes" : 79957,
            "leaf page multi-block writes" : 3847381,
            "maximum blocks required for a page" : 870,
            "internal-page overflow keys" : 0,
            "leaf-page overflow keys" : 0,
            "overflow values written" : 0,
            "pages deleted" : 9135126,
            "page checksum matches" : 2604439,
            "page reconciliation calls" : 62629072,
            "page reconciliation calls for eviction" : 60930354,
            "leaf page key bytes discarded using prefix compression" : 0,
            "internal page key bytes discarded using suffix compression" : 177193166
        },
        "session" : {
            "object compaction" : 0,
            "open cursor count" : 4043133
        },
        "transaction" : {
            "update conflicts" : 0
        }
    },
    "nindexes" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 0,
    "indexSizes" : {

    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "$gleStats" : {
        "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "electionId" : ObjectId("5614f9ebaffca08a80d27834")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem in the past, and it was related to an unsync time between the servers and a VM bug with bios time and ntp.

Are replication members sharing a same ntp server for syncing the time?

Comment: @ignivs - Yes, in both cases - (from /etc/ntp.conf) "server 0.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst" etc

Comment: Sure the oplog might reside on a volume with 50GB of free space, but what's the actual limit on the oplog.rs capped collection?

Comment: @Wesley - I've updated the post to show the size of the oplog. I'd totally forgotten that this collection was capped.

Comment: @MarcF That's the replica length at that specific moment in time, but not the oplog size. What's the size of the "maxsize" field in the oplog.rs collection's stats? What's likely in my experience is that there is a point where there's a large amount of writes at a point in time that causes secondaries to fall out of sync. By the time you notice and check out the oplog's start to end length, there's 0.62 hours which may be enough time, but at the time the secondary fell out of sync it may have been mere seconds worth of time.

Comment: @Wesley - Have included a full dump of oplog stats.

Comment: @MarcF Okay cool, so the oplog is 32GB now, but it's also only representing 0.6 hours of time. That tells me that it's a very write heavy database. In my experience 1) There is no reason that a secondary would crash because the primary ran out of logging space. It might be a correlation, but it's not a cause. 2) That short of an amount of time represented in that large of an oplog implies lots of writes, and it's been my experience that write-heavy databases can have periods of activity that shrink the oplog to mere seconds and that causes secondaries to have a hard time staying in sync.

Comment: @MarcF You can test for this by doing some relatively simple `grep | sort | wc -l` style one liners that look through all of the logs and count the amount of write operations that were logged (logs by default only write queries that took longer than 100ms, but this is still a reasonable start to troubleshooting). You may see that during the hour that the secondary fell out of sync, the primary had an enormous amount of write operations logged that was larger than the norm.